# Prevent focus change in a form when the form activates by click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible in a C# WinForms app to click anywhere on an unfocused form (to focus the form), without also focusing / selecting any controls at the click point?

I'm trying to mimic the way Excel works where if you click on an unfocused Excel workbook / sheet, it will focus (and bring to front) the workbook / sheet BUT will not change the selected cell.

Comment: maybe set `this.ActiveControl = null`in the formactivate ? (I hate this focus style of excel btw)

Answer (score 3):

You can override [`WndProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and handle [`WM_MOUSEACTIVATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mouseactivate?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), then check if the current form is not active form, set `MA_ACTIVATEANDEAT` as result to activate the window, and discard the mouse message.

```
const int WM_MOUSEACTIVATE = 0x0021;
const int MA_ACTIVATEANDEAT = 2;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEACTIVATE && Form.ActiveForm != this)
        m.Result = (IntPtr)MA_ACTIVATEANDEAT;
    else
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Using above code, when you click on another form or one of its controls, the other form activates, but the clicked control doesn't receive mouse click and the the active control on the other form will not change.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is uses 2 handlers, Form deactivated and Form Activated:

```
private void Form_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Enabled = true;
}

private void Form_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Also could be used `DataGridView's` focus handlers if you want inform control like this.